# Lucene find the document with most intersections

Tags: solr, lucene

I want to implement the function of "mutual friends" in Lucene, so I have many documents with a list of friends.

```
DOC:
    id: p1
    name: Mike
    profile_id: 1
    friends_id: [2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
```

or

```
id: p3
name: John
profile_id: 3
friends_id: [6,7,8,9,10]
```

or

```
 id: p5
    name: Roftl
    profile_id: 5
    friends_id: [1,2,3,6,10]
```

If I were the account Mike, I'd like to find with a Lucene query another account with the higher numer of mutual friends. If it would be possible, also adding the field in the response with that number.

Answer (score 0):

You may try following steps.

1) Access the termvector for the Mike document.

2) Access the terms in the field friends_id

3) Iterate those terms (i.e. friend_ids) and form a boolean query of term queries.

4) Search the index with that query.

5) Assuming that you don't have duplicate terms in friends_id filed, it should work. The top result should match your requirements.

It's even better as Lucene provides MoreLikeThisQuery to achieve similar documents for provided terms in the query.

To be brief, this query is used to find similar documents for a candidate document. What it does is nothing but above steps. In your use-case, you are not looking for a similar document for a candidate document, but for the top-similar document for a field in a document.

Here's the sample code for [MoreLikeThisQuery](http://java.dzone.com/articles/lucene-morelikethis-example)

[Another tutorial](http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/)